# Selenium explicit wait for LinkedIn spinning circles

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, linkedin-api

I am using Selenium and its Python bindings to webscrape from LinkedIn for a research project. I webscrape people's profiles.

In LinkedIn, when you load a person profile, the site puts spinning circles until the experiences and the education are fully loaded. 
I want Selenium to wait until the spinning circles disappear, in order to get, in the HTML source code, the experience and the education sections.

So my question is: How can I code an explicit wait for the LinkedIn spinning circles?

EDIT: a more precise question would be: **How can I get a locator for the spinning circles?** 
There is no time to do that from the browser development tools. They disappear too fast

EDIT 2: Another point. A person may or may not have an education section. So clicking or otherwise checking for the education section to be present is not a solution. The education section may not be present either because there is no education section (the person did not put any information on LinkedIn, which therefore is not putting an education section in the DOM) or because it is not loaded yet (there is a spinning circle). I want to know which one it is. If it is the second reason (there is a spinning circle), I want to wait. (the section is a `div` with a class named `education-section`). The same applies for the experiences

Here is the core of the project for the purpose of this question.

These are 2 functions inside of a class. `self.getBrowser()` return a WebDriver object. For the sake of clarity and brevity I have cut the non-interesting parts, including code inside the 2 functions, so the arguments which seems to not be used in reality are. I hope the remaining variables are self-explaining.

```
def waitForPresenceCondition(self, by, value, sleep = True, check_for_404 = True):
    try:
        condition = EC.visibility_of_element_located((by, value))
        WebDriverWait(self.getBrowser(), self.wait_timeout).until(condition)
    except TimeoutException:
        logging.critical("Timed out waiting for page element. Fatal. Exiting")
        raise
    except:
        logging.error("Unexpected exception waiting for page element. Exiting")
        raise
    else:
        logging.debug("Element found in URL")

# Scrape an organization
def scrape(self, url):
   self.getBrowser().get(url)
   try:
       self.waitForPresenceCondition(By.CLASS_NAME, "pv-profile-wrapper")
   except Error404:
       logging.info("waitForPresenceCondition raised 404 error. Returning False")
       return False
    #INSERT HERE EXPLICIT WAIT FOR THE SPINNING CIRCLES
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spinning wheels have a class named `artdeco-spinner`

I have found it by inserting a breakpoint in Chrome DevTools

Follow [this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#event-listeners) guide and insert a breakpoint on "Animation" events

Then as suggested by @Andersson I have used Selenium `invisibility_of_element_located` function, which waits for a `locator` to be either invisible or not attached anymore to the DOM. I don't need to distinguish the 2 cases

```
def waitForInvisibility(self, by, value):
    condition_str = "(" + str(by) + "," + value + ")"
    url = self.getBrowserURL()
    msg = "Waiting for in-visibility of "
    msg += condition_str
    msg += " in URL='" + url + "'"
    logging.info(msg)
    try:
        condition = EC.invisibility_of_element_located((by, value))
        WebDriverWait(self.getBrowser(), self.wait_timeout).until(condition)
    except TimeoutException:
        logging.critical("Timed out waiting for element invisibility. Exiting")
        raise
    except:
        logging.error("Unexpected exception waiting for element invisibility. Exiting")
        raise
    else:
        logging.debug("Element " + condition_str + " is now invisible in URL='" + url + "'")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update your code like below:

```
def waitForPresenceCondition(self, by, value, sleep=True, check_for_404=True, visible=True):
    try:
        if visible:
            condition = EC.visibility_of_element_located((by, value))
        else:
            condition = EC.invisibility_of_element_located((by, value))
        WebDriverWait(self.getBrowser(), self.wait_timeout).until(condition)
```

This should allow you to use your `waitForPresenceCondition()` with `visible=False` parameter to wait until `div` with spinning circles dissapear

Comment: The problem is: how can I get a locator for the spinning circles? There is no time to do that from the browser delevopment tools. They disappear too fast

Comment: You can try to make a `click()` on element which is covered by `div` with those circles and you should get something like `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is not clickable at point (411, 675). Other element would receive the click:  here comes HTML for the target div`. You can use `HTML` sample from exception to make a selector

Comment: Can you be more specific? When you load the profile, you get the spinning circles. After some time, those spinning circles go away on their own (so probably it's all handled via AJAX). "After some time" vary a lot, but it's not enough for me to select the spinning circles from the development tool and see if they have some proprietary class or id I can use as selector